# function signature pattern: args slide left over undefined slots during invocation

Tags: javascript, function, naming-conventions, api-design

I am implementing some functions in JavaScript that take very flexible argument lists.

The signature looks something like this:

```
function foo([string], [array], [boolean])
```

It is often the case that the consumer may not have all of the parameters to pass in.

For example, not having the array (2nd) param but having the boolean (3rd) param. Or not having the first string param, but having the (2nd) array param, etc...

An API goal is to relieve the consumer from having to invoke the functions in this way:

```
foo('s', undefined, true)
foo(undefined, [1,2])
foo(undefined, undefined, true)
```

Since the function parameters have unique types, I can parse the arguments in a way that allows the `undefined` params to be skipped.

The previous invocation examples can then turn into this:

```
foo('s', true)
foo([1,2])
foo(true)
```

I understand that it is debatable whether or not this API pattern is clean or not, but setting that aside, my question is **what is this type of function argument scheme called?**

It's more than just function overloading because the arguments can "slide to the left" to cover the undefined cases.

Once I can correctly name this scheme I can improve my documentation.

Comment: I've seen lots of JavaScript code that does that, but I've never seen any documentation use any term to describe that as a design practice. Effectively it's kind-of like overloading in C++ or Java.

Comment: Something similar conceptually in c# is *named arguments*

Comment: @Pointy do remember which projects you had seen this practice used in?

Comment: Well jQuery does it all over the place, also Velocity.js (kind-of). I mean, it's pretty common really, and since there's no actual type-checked method overloading you have to write the code explicitly to do it.